# How write text on an existing xlsx file with the help of openpyxl on python?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Most of the tutorials are outdated and I am unsuccessful at writing on an xlsx file with the help of python.

Here is some code I used:

```
import openpyxl 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/user/Desktop/pytranslate.xlsx')
path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/pytranslate.xlsx'
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws.cell(row = 1,column = 1,value = 'need for meas')
val1 = ws['A1'].value
print(val1)
wb.save(path)
```

The program ends with no error but I cannot see any output on the xlsx file.

Comment: Try saving the file under a different name. This will show if things are working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to test. I created an empty excel document first. It updated correctly.

```
import openpyxl 
path = 'pytranslate.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws.cell(row = 1,column = 1,value = 'need for meas')
val1 = ws['A1'].value
print(val1)
wb.save(path)
```

Output (excel)

[image: Excel]

If your document is not updating, confirm you have correct permissions to the file and folder.

Comment: Just realised that I do not have permissions for python. How to edit permissions for this?

Comment: Open a cmd prompt and enter `python --version`. See if you get an error.

Comment: Got Errno [2]: No Such File or Directory

Comment: Be sure the folder is correct. My code had the xlsx file in the same folder as the script for testing. You file should probably be `'C:/Users/user/Desktop/pytranslate.xlsx'`

Comment: Sorry - I was thinking of the excel file. If python not found, add the python folder to your path. If you don't have a python folder, you need to install python.